# How to get the 32-bit twos-complement bit pattern of an int?

Tags: python

Is there some way to get the actual bit representation, instead of the garbage '-0bx'? I need to actually be able to see the bits. Whether or not it comes out big/little endian doesn't matter. This is for an assignment. 
Does anyone know how to view the actual 2's complement bit representation of an integer in python?

Comment: By "actual bit representation," do you mean the two's complement representation?

Comment: What type of number?  Are you talking about `int`?  `float`?  `long`?

Comment: Yes, the 2's complement represenation in memory.

Comment: Do you want the string to contain the infinitely many notional '1' bits on the left required for arbitrary-precision integers?

Comment: @Wooble No, I'd like to see the 32 bit integer 2's complement representation

Comment: Come on guys, I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough at first. Of course python numbers are infinite, but I know that the default is a 32-bit int. So how can I see the 'real' bit representation of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the number isn't constrained to a bit range, there is no canonical "the bits" representation.  The output would be `0b1`, `0b11111111`, `0b1111111111111111`, etc. depending on which bit range you happened to intend.

Would the following give what you want?

```
> x = -1
> print(bin(x & 0xffffffff)) # 32-bit output
0b11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Note: This doesn't pad with `0`es to give a fixed length, as Ned's suggestion does.

Comment: Applying the binary AND operator `&` coerces the value into a bounded representation before applying the bitmask to constrain it to your desired bit width.

Comment: Any idea now how I would convert it back to an int?

Comment: To convert it back to an int: `y = int(bin(x & 0xffffffff), 2)` then `y = -(2**31)*bool(y & 0x80000000) + (y & 0x7fffffff)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = -1
>>> "{:032b}".format(x & 0xffffffff)
'11111111111111111111111111111111'
```